# php Trouble getting wsdl file to send two functions

Tags: php

I an trying to make a web service in PHP and I am using WSDL.

here is a snippet of my WSDL

```
 <wsdl:portType name="MyWSDLFilePort">
    <wsdl:operation name="funcA">
                    <documentation>this does something.</documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:mGetRequest"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:mGetResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="funcB">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:mGetRequest"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:mGetResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

I want to have two seperate functions in my WSDL, and I would like them to do different things. 
The problem I have is that it looks like funcA and funcB are doing the same thing, ie 
In my client I add a function called funcA which returns "I am func A" and in funcB i have one that returns "I am func B". In the WSDL Client I call either funcA or B and I get "I am func A".
If you want me to post the wsdl here I can do so.

Just as a side note, This is my first post on stack overflow. My English may be bad and my descriptions terrible. I apologize in advance.

Comment: Oh shoot sorry about that. There was a typo. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your WSDL it's likely that you've hit [this bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49169).  (Ironically, at the time of writing the PHP bug server is down, but you should be able to pull the content from Google cache if you search for "php bug 49169").  The effect of this bug is that if you've got 2 functions, funcA and funcB which have the same signature, PHP looks up the function in the WSDL at run time based on the function signature, and uses the first one it comes across.  Therefore, in your example, I'd expect calls to funcA and funcB to always be handled as funcA, as this is defined first.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I frigged my WSDL to not have the same signature for any of the operations that it contains.  Other than that you could use RPC style (i.e. no WSDL), use NuSOAP or use WS02 for PHP.  Or you could fix the bug ;-)